# How to selectively print certain lines of text with a word a user enters

Tags: java, string

I have a file of multiple lines saved on my computer. In my java program, I am trying to ask the user to enter a string of letters or a word, and then have the program print out the lines only where that string of letters or word is. I know I have to import the scanner class, but how do I print out these user-specified lines?

Also, these lines of text are numbered (1-20). How do I print out just the text characters and ignore the integers when reprinting the original code? For example, one line of the code is "1. example of the first line of code"

Below is my code I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

BufferedReader reader = null;
ArrayList <String> myFileLines = new ArrayList <String>();

try {

    String sCurrentLine;

    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/wolftrek/Downloads/example.txt"));

    while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        myFileLines.add(sCurrentLine);

        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try {

        if (reader != null)reader.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}



for (int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
    if (myFileLines.get(i).contains("example word")) {
        System.out.println(myFileLines.get(i));
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: One way, use `Scanner` class to get user input

Comment: I know I can import the scanner class and ask the user for that. But how do I collect that word or letters from the user and print only those specific lines?

Comment: At the moment you are looping for `example word` - change that to your user inputted String

Comment: I think I got it to work, does this look right?

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
  String enteredString = "";
  
  System.out.println("Please enter the characters to search for: ");
  enteredString = myScanner.next();
  
  for(int i = 0; i < myFileLines.size(); i++) {
   if (myFileLines.get(i).contains(enteredString)) {
    System.out.println(myFileLines.get(i));

Comment: well done, it looks like it will work, although I would use `nextLine` rather than `next`

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying, I changed it to nextLine. Do you know how I can reprint the lines of code without the numbers in the beginning of each line? I am aware of "char at" but I don't think that's the best way to go about it because 1-9 and one digits, and 10-20 are two digits. How can I print just text and ignore integers?

Comment: Are the numbers in the text file?

Comment: Yeah, the text is like this:
"1. first line of text
2. second line of text
3. third line of text"

so my question is how to print everything but the 1. 2. and 3.

Comment: Consider this code `String [] arr = {"1. line 1", "2. line 2", "3. line 3"};
  
  for (String str : arr) {
   System.out.println(str.replaceAll("^\\d+\\. ", ""));
  }`

Comment: The text file has about 20 lines of code so that probably isn't the most efficient way because I would have to type out each line. Also, if the text file was to change, the code wouldn't work. Any suggestions on how I can universally ignore the integers?

Comment: you obviously did not understand my comment.  It is demo how to use `replaceAll` to change *number.* to *blank space*  Of course you should continue to use your input file